# Why some programmers use this "if" condition (and what to do to make it work)

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement

Why many programmers use:

```
if ($_GET['var'] or $this->error)
```

instead of

```
if (isset($_GET['var']) or isset($this->error)
```

without adding

```
        error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE )
```

or, (shorter but slower)

```
        if (@$_GET['var'] or @$this->error)
```

...or something similar ?

Do you need to somehow (?) configure php in the ini file to suppress the errors on non-existing variables and properties to use the "feature" or is it simply a bad practice one should avoid?

Comment: are u sure they not included any framework !?

Comment: there is nothing "slow" in @. Using @'s makes your code stupid, not slow.

Comment: it can be a simple class like: [SQL tutorial](http://www.php.rk.edu.pl/w/p/obsluga-baz-sqlite/) (it's in Polish, but the example is clear), or it can be inside of a framework project (and on my localhost it still triggers unnecessary notices).

Comment: There is a performance hit for using "@".  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#102543

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel: I've just read on another forum, @ is slower because the whole notice is generated, but not shown, or maybe because each time the error reporting mode is temp changed (multiple theories). Oh, well :).

Comment: but to stay on topic: what is the "correct" syntax of conditions for variables and properties that may or may not exist, and/or how to configure php for the shortened form demonstrated in the above code ?

Comment: "another forum" doesn't mean "undisputed source of wisdom". there are thousands wild rumors and superstitions about PHP, and this one is one of them. In practice you'd never notice the difference. That's the problem: everyone here just repeat what they read somewhere but nobody have practical experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to me like bast practice at all. As you said correctly, without setting the error_reporting, PHP would throw many warnings on specific cases (where the variables weren't set).

Using isset seems to me like the best way.

Comment: [Not true](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), however they got different precedences.

Comment: Ha! wow, i've been developing with PHP for quite a few years and never stumbled upon that. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: So, resuming, (`Or` exists and there's a precedence of logical operators etc.), but this syntax for non-existent variables is technically an error = bad practice, and the way the programmers get away with the errors is by configuring their php.ini like in a [link](http://www.computerworld.com.au/article/191904/error_reporting_php_part/), right ?

Comment: Exactly. They don't get away with the errors, they just bury them in configuration :)

Answer (score 6):

> or is it simply a bad practice one should avoid?

Definitely **yes**. It's a bad practice to suppress or ignore errors.

Answer (score 0):

They will use it because it´s faster to type. And they may not think all problems it may cause.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the "correct" syntax of conditions for variables and properties that may or may not exist

Unfortunately, there is none.

**Every variable used in the code should be defined first.** That's the only good practice, if you want one.

So, for the class properties it's easy - it's already commonplace that every one of them should be defined in the class definition.

For the outside variables it's less obvious.
There is no single scenario.
Say, if program flow depends on the existence of GET variable, it's OK *to check if it's set**

```
if (isset($GET['page'])) ...
```

note that we're not using this variable contents but only checking it's existence!

otherwise, if we expect `page` to be always set, we have to check it first, and **set a default value** if not. and then use that new variable instead of $_GET one.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Col. Shrapnel ! I was mainly wondering about the syntax used by some programmers: if it's a secret and better way of constructing the `if` condition, or is it their mere laziness :).

Comment: in fact you were wondering of the things quoted at the top of my answer